# How to Format a Double to get rid of 0's

Tags: java, string, int, double

I'm trying to format a double, such as `99928.000000` to read only `99928`. I know that I could change it to an integer, but the data I'm reading in has leading 0's that integers don't pick up. Could I somehow format it to read only `99928`.

```
String result = String.format("%f %s,%s (%1.3f; %1.3f)",zip, city, state, latitude,longitude);
```

Current code^^ Thanks for your time.

Comment: Er... what data types are the variables currently if they keep leading zeroes?

Comment: Post your initial string.

Comment: It makes more sense to store a zip code as a `String` than as a `double`.  You can't do arithmetic with them (I live halfway between Los Angeles and San Francisco perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

You've specified three decimal places by writing .3, so you're getting them. If you don't want them, don't specify them.

I don't know what you mean by 'leading zeros that integers don't pick up'. Neither doubles nor integers contain leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DecimalFormat` to create a `String` with leading zeroes to format a zip code.  With this code:

```
DecimalFormat pattern = new DecimalFormat("00000");
String zip = pattern.format(99928.0);
System.out.println(String.format("%s", zip));
```

The output is:

```
99928
```

Incidentally, because there are leading zeroes in a zip code, it shouldn't be read as any numeric data type.  You should read and store it as a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are storing `99928.000000` as a string, if you are able to keep leading zeroes.

In this case, you should be able to get what you want by using string splitting on the decimal point.

```
String foo = "99928.000000"
foo = foo.split("\\.")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) , it says

```
#   Number  Yes Digit, zero shows as absent
```

For more details please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502976/decimalformat-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

for zip code you shall mask it with "%5.0f", as following

```
String result = String.format("%5.0f %s,%s (%1.3f; %1.3f)", zip, city, state, latitude, longitude);
```

may be this could help